# Difficulty in sorting the data from the Products table by the related Descriptions table using Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, psql

I have run into this kind of difficulty.

i have 2 psql tables linked by `Planet.hasMany(Descriptions)`

Planets

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1. | Jupiter |
| 2. | Mars |
| 3. | Pluto |

Descriptions

| id | planetId | title | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | “distance to the sun” | 1000km |
| 2 | 1 | “surface temperature” | 158* |
| 3 | 1 | “color” | green |
| 4 | 2 | “distance to the sun” | 476km |
| 5 | 2 | “surface temperature” | 56* |
| 6 | 2 | “color” | red |
| 7 | 3 | “distance to the sun” | 2500km |
| 8 | 3 | “surface temperature” | -257* |
| 9 | 3 | “color” | blue |

I want to display the planets by related characteristics!

```
Planet.findAll({include: {model: “Descriptions”, where: {title: “distance to the sun”, description: “1000km” }}})
```

In this case it will work correctly. But what if I want to display planets that match several descriptions. As soon as I didn’t try and didn’t do anything, the conclusion comes out wrong. For example

```
Planet.findAll({include: {model: “Descriptions”, where: [
{title: “distance to the sun”, description: “1000km” },
{title: “color”, description: “green” }
]}})
```

а так же

```
Planet.findAll({include: {model: “Descriptions”, where: {[Op.or]: [
{title: “distance to the sun”, description: “1000km” },
{title: “color”, description: “green” }
]}}})
```

Such a search will give me only planets that match by 1 array element. Maybe I approached the issue of sorting from the wrong side. Tell me what I'm doing wrong, or at least send me something to watch or read. Thank you in advance

Comment: Op.or -> Op.and?